# visualizar valores distintos en dos tablas en sql

Tags: sql, join

Tengo dos tablas A Y B en sql.

En la tabla A:

```
Nombre| Apellido1 |Apellido2 
----------------------------
Daniel| Renteria  |Galicia
Pedro | Paramo    |Hernandez
David | Martínez  |Perez
```

En la tabla B:

```
Nombre| 
-------
Daniel
Pedro 
Juan
Pamela
```

Quiero los nombres que no están en la tabla A con la siguiente consulta:

```
select b.*, a* 
from A a right join B b 
on a.Nombre = b.Nombre 
where a.Nombre is null
```

Comment: Que tal, la consulta que estas buscando es: ```SELECT B.Nombre
FROM TablaB B
LEFT JOIN TablaA A ON B.Nombre = A.Nombre
WHERE A.Nombre IS NULL;```

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene la respuesta (aunque no sea la ideal). ¿Podrías aclarar cuál es tu problema?

Comment: Hola Erick, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles, y de haberlo sido marcar como aceptada la que consideres que más te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una **subconsulta** con el **operador not in**:

```
select nombre
from TablaB
where nombre not in (select nombre from TablaA);
```

Aquí se obtienen los nombres de **TablaB** que no están incluidos en los nombres de **TablaA**, la **subconsulta** obtiene todos los nombres de **TablaA**, y usando el **operador not in** filtramos los nombres de **TablaB** que no están incluidos en **TablaA**.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM b AS tabla_1
LEFT JOIN a AS tabla_2
ON tabla_1.nombre = 
tabla_2.nombre
WHERE tabla_2.nombre IS NULL
```

Con esta consulta relacionas la tabla A y B apartir de la columna nombre con un LEFT JOIN , al colocar IS NULL en el WHERE indicas que solo te debe mostrar los nombre que estan en la tabla B pero no en la tabla A.